# jQuery Convert Object Array to Array with keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

I have an object array which looks like:

```
Object {0: "Ma. Jessa Martinez", 1: "Edwin Cuevas", 2: "Gerum Generol", 3: "Roy delos Reyes", 4: "Hannah Montecillo", 5: "Ralph Turla", 6: "Edralyn Danabar", 7: "Angelo Sto Domingo", 8: "Rhina Dela Cruz", 9: "Ricardo Camara", 10: "Joene Floresca"}
```

And I want to convert in array like:

```
[[0,"Ma. Jessa Martinez"],[1,"Edwin Cuevas"],[2,"Gerum Generol"], and so on]
```

I tried using

```
 var myobj_array= $.map(ticks, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
 });
```

But it only return the values with no keys:

```
["Ma. Jessa Martinez", "Edwin Cuevas", "Gerum Generol", "Roy delos Reyes", "Hannah Montecillo", "Ralph Turla", "Edralyn Danabar", "Angelo Sto Domingo", "Rhina Dela Cruz", "Ricardo Camara", "Joene Floresca"]
```

Is there other way? I've search already in google I can't find a similar thing.

**EDIT** To be clear where my object array came from, I added this for reference. It came from an ajax request and already sorted:

```
var ticks = {};
$.each(result, function(key,value) {
    ticks[key] = value.name;
});
```

Comment: You dont need to build an array like `[[0,"Ma. Jessa Martinez"],[1,"Edwin Cuevas"],[2,"Gerum Generol"], and so on]`. You can already access your flat array with `your_array[num_key]` i.e. `array[0] = "Ma. Jessa Martinez"`.

Comment: @PinkTurtle that's right, but in this question is wrong. Because an user can have another number instead 0, then it wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: Hi thanks guys. My data is correct and will always start from zero and is sorted. I will use it as a label in a Bar Graph Flot Charts and it requires the fortmat I mentioned above :) Thanks for the help I'll select Carlos's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use instead :

```
var myobj_array= $.map(ticks, function(value, index) {
    return [[index,value]];
});

console.log(myobj_array);
```

@PinkTurtle point is important, because we may pay attention to the performance or use vanillajs instead jQuery.

However if the object structure use instead :

```
{80: "Ma. Jessa Martinez", 12: "Edwin Cuevas"}
```

and we process with only the index (and we retrieve it like `arr[80]` would be undefined, only if we use `arr[0]` would work, but the index of the user is not 0 , is 80).

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I already edited my question to explain where my object array came from. Feel free to check and if you could suggest a better way to do what I need. Thanks

Comment: @Carlos are you sure the extra brackets pair around `[index,value]` is correct/mandatory ?

Comment: he said he WANTS a structure like : [ [0,"Ma. Jessa Martinez"] ] (array that contains an array with indexes 0:id and 1:name). He can make a loop to process it when it's an object, but maybe he finds easily making it with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use normal js:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       arr.push([i, obj[i]]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new Javascript object and return as follow:

```
 var myobj_array= $.map(ticks, function(value, index) {
   Var obj=[[index,value]];
  return obj;
 });
```